# How to change the option item when I click on the fist option label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms

I'm setting the 7 option item on the webpage.
How to change the option item when I click on the fist option label?

- (Image of the code)
- ■option1 A, B, C
- □option2 (A:10, B:20, C:30)
- □option3 (A:15, B:25, C:35)
- ...
- □option7 (A:18, B:28, C:38)
- (Result)
- In the case of choosing A button of option1
- Option2 ->10
- Option3 ->15
- ...
- Option7 ->18

(Real codesample)

```
Selection of A, B, C
<select name="preset" id="SaveAccount3" type="submit" value="option1" />
                 <option value="A">A</option>
                 <option value="B">B</option>
                 <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<ul id="measureid">
            <li><label for="CreditcardMonth">option2</label>
            <select id="measureidsize1" name="measure1" class="chkselect">
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
            </select></li>

            <li><label for="CreditcardMonth">option3</label>
            <select id="measureidsize1" name="measure1" class="chkselect">
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="35">35</option>
            </select></li>

<!-- abbreviation -->

            <li><label for="CreditcardMonth">option7</label>
            <select id="measureidsize1" name="measure1" class="chkselect">
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
                <option value="38">38</option>
            </select></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/z87qf/1/

```
$('#SaveAccount3').change(function(){
    var option = $("option:selected", this).val();
    option == "A"? (opt=0) : (option == "B"? (opt=1): (opt=2))
    $.each($('select[class=chkselect]'),function(i){
        $('select[id=measureidsize'+i+'] option:eq('+opt+')').attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
});
```

Is this your requirement?

Comment: Thanks so much, and I was surprised coz its my first time to see this --> http://jsfiddle.net/z87qf/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery and do something like this.

Using change event and setting the values accordingly.

Following code is just to get you started.

```
$('#SaveAccount3').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();

    //you can write your logic with if-else or switch construct

    $('#measureidsize1').val('50'); //you can set value like this
    //if you set value beside what is there in options for that select box it won't set

});
```